# Unable to get Debian guest full screen on VMware Player 12

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have installed a Debian 8 guest on VMware Player 12 but I cannot get the Debian screen to fill my whole monitor even in Full Screen mode.

When I set it up, I set screen size to be the same as the host display, and subsequently I have installed open-vm-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop on the guest, but still cannot see how to make this happen, or how to use the desktop tools which VMware say are for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If, after installing open-vm-tools, you still don't get a good resolution, you can do this:

1. Check your current System Resolution (Host System)
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` (as root)
3. Uncomment the line `GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600` (Your screen resolution here mine was 1920x1080)
4. Save the file
5. Execute the command `update-grub` (as root)
6. Reboot (`shutdown -r now`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have X server installed on your guest, you might need the xorg vmware video drivers.

I had to install xf86-video-vmware package on Archlinux guest on ESXi host to get the proper resolutions. On Debian you might have to install the following video driver package

https://packages.debian.org/stable/x11/xserver-xorg-video-vmware

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps involved, I can get you started...

1. Search CD in your Debian desktop, eject anything that is mounted there.
2. In the VMWare Player menus: Player->Manage->Install VMWare Tools.
3. Copy and Extract the VMWare Tools to another folder.
4. Read through the ReadMe; it is better to install via Bash (but you are a Debian user, so you know that already).

If you are still having issues, this video can help (it is for Linux Mint, but the idea is the same): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U8mnEg7nEw

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange sites. Unfortunately, answering by suggesting to read the manual is not considered acceptable here. You ought to make an effort and specify how to install VMWare tools in some detail, and why this helps with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I have encoutered the same problem even having open-vm-tools installed, but I've found a solution. You can try to change the screen resolution in the guest Debian system. By default it is set to 800x600. You should set it to the bigger values, for instance - 1024x768 and more. Hope it will help you to enlarge the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

It's too simple. At the initial phase, I was also in trouble then after 2-3 hours, I got the solution.

1.If you are using a click on display setting bottom of the Refresh tab after that you have to check your display resolution like mine is 1366*766 similarly You have to check yours.

2. Go to Debian VMware & on the desktop click the right mouse tap and click on display setting then feed the same resolution here.
3. But problem is that apply option is not showing because of resolution. You have to drag that setting panel using a mouse and then apply it.

If you succeed it give some money or food to poor people or animal which is near you.